# Android getActionBar() returns null when I touch hard menu button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have action bar and menu located in action bar.

When I touch hard menu button `getActionBar()` returns null.

Third at the bottom is what I mean with hard menu button:

[image: hard menu button]

I can prevent app to crash as: `if(getActionBar() != null) { // ... }`

But it's not what I want to do. I need the action bar items to modification (add/remove). So I am not able to do while `getActionBar()` returns null.

Anyone has any idea why `getActionBar()` returns null?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (getActionBar() != null) { // Action bar is null here when I click hard menu button.
                getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        // Some logical operations here.

    // Get the menu.
    BaseActivity.menuOnActionBar = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);   
}
```

In my activity, after refresh completes I remove action view (action view was set to xml right after refresh clicked in order to show progress bar):

```
menuOnActionBar.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null); // This throws an error.
```

And `menuOnActionBar` variable definition in `BaseActivity`:

```
public static Menu menuOnActionBar;
```

Thrown error is: `E/AndroidRuntime(4193): java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: "Third at the bottom is what I mean with hard menu button" -- based on the icon, that is the RECENTS button, not the MENU button.

Comment: @CommonsWare true, but i think HTC allows to change it to behave like the menu button (because of complaints from users that for old apps, there is a huge menu button on screen).

Comment: @JustWork can you please show some code? it's not clear what you want...

Comment: @CommonsWare as "android developer" said it is possible to change it to behave like menu button under: settings > displays, gestures & buttons > recent apps button > press for menu, press and hold for recent apps.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the action bar items to modification (add/remove).

First, you do not need an `ActionBar` instance for that, as you cannot affect action bar items through `ActionBar` anyway. If you are adding or removing action bar items, [call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on your `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29), which will force Android to call `onCreateOptionsMenu()` again.

More importantly, you should not be doing that as a result of a MENU press, as by then it is too late. Instead, call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when something changes in the state of your application that requires a change in the mix of action bar items.

If you need to change something else about the action bar (e.g., tabs), that is where `getActionBar()` becomes more relevant. Two scenarios in which I know that `getActionBar()` will return `null` are:

- You do not have an action bar
- You are extending an ActionBarSherlock class (e.g., `SherlockActivity`), in which case you need to be calling `getSupportActionBar()`